# How the dead nodes are handled in AWS OpenSearch?

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

Trying to understand what is the right approach to connect to AWS OpenSearch (single cluster, multiple data nodes).

To my understanding, as long as data nodes are behind the load balancer (according to this and other AWS docs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/set-access-control-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service/), we can not use:

```
var pool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
```

and we probably should not use `CloudConnectionPool` - as originally it was dedicated to elastic search cloud and was left in open search client by mistake?

Hence we use `SingleNodeConnectionPool` and it works, but I've noticed several exceptions, which indicated that node had `DeadUntil` set to date one hour in advance - so I was wondering if that is expected behavior, as from client's perspective that is the only node it knows about?

What is correct way to connect to AWS OpenSearch that has multiple nodes and should I be concerned about DeadUntil property?